# align icon with textbox bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want the icon to be aligned with the text box and centered on the container

i tried this but the icon stay upper than text box

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center" id="baseContainer">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" class="input-form col-sm-3 offset-sm-0" id="searchForm" placeholder="Busque um filme ou série">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass col-sm" onclick="foo()"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

and if i remove the row and container div, stay the way i want but uncentered

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a class **align-items-center** to the **row**

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center" id="baseContainer">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <input type="text" class="input-form col-sm-3 offset-sm-0" id="searchForm" placeholder="Busque um filme ou série">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass col-sm" onclick="foo()"></i>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to align the search icon vertically:

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center" id="baseContainer">
  <div class="row">
    <input
      type="text"
      class="input-form col-sm-3 offset-sm-0"
      id="searchForm"
      placeholder="Busque um filme ou série"
    />
    <i
      class="fa-solid fa-magnifying-glass col-sm d-flex align-items-center"
      onclick="foo()"
    ></i>
  </div>
</div>
```